# ServiceStack XML Bomb and External Entity Attacks

Tags: security, servicestack

I read an older article (circa 2009) on MS' site regarding
[XML Denial of Service Attacks and Defenses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx).

I'm curious if ServiceStack is vulnerable to these and how one would apply the following recommendation from MS if it's necessary.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 1024;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you ever got an answer. I'm seeing the vulnerability and need to mitigate.

Answer (score 0):

This is now [disabled this by default](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/9c1467e0aef2465617b00d32755bc36951540c5d) from v5.0.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).